# Consolidating multiple rows to a single row

Tags: reportingservices-2005, reporting-services, ssrs-grouping

Is it possible to join multiple row values to a single row? The stored procedure from where I acquire the data that I use return multiple, almost identical rows except that the *category*-column dfferentiates for products that have been assigned multiple categories. I would like to consolidate these categories to one column, separated by new lines. Example data:

```
Name        Article number   Sales    Sales Category
------------------------------------------------
Product 1   2059102-1        20520    Retailer 1
------------------------------------------------
Product 1   2059102-1        20520    Retailer 2
------------------------------------------------
Product 1   2059102-1        20520    Retailer 3
------------------------------------------------
Product 2   2059102-2        2050     Retailer 1
------------------------------------------------
Product 2   2059102-2        5302     Retailer 3
```

Desired result:

```
Name        Article number   Sales    Sales Category
------------------------------------------------
Product 1   2059102-1        20520    Retailer 1
                                      Retailer 2
                                      Retailer 3
------------------------------------------------
Product 2   2059102-2        2050     Retailer 1
                                      Retailer 3
```

Thank you!

Comment: Does it has to be a line break in Sales Category?

Comment: Yes, unfortunately that's what our client has specified.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Create an RDL table and setup a Grouping on the Detail section of the table with *two* grouping expressions (so you have a single Grouping in the Table Details, but with multiple grouping expressions). The grouping expressions should be one for each of the fields: Name, Article number.

Then put a column in the RDL table for each field (Name, Article number, Sales, Sales Category). The trick is putting a List control in the Sales Category cell. In the list add a textbox for the "Sales Category" field and I think you'll get the result you want.

There is also some nasty [SQL tricks for "row concatenation"](https://www.simple-talk.com/sql/t-sql-programming/concatenating-row-values-in-transact-sql/), but that is not very maintainable IMHO.

Comment: I think that export in excel doesn't work in this case (Data Regions within table/matrix cells are ignored.)

Comment: Been searching for this solution for 2 days. Thanks for solving it in 2011! (upvote)